# MySQL url column contains items with unwanted double forward slash

Tags: mysql, replace

Table: **pages**

Field: **url**

Issue: http://google.com//search?q=something

I have a few thousand rows where this has happened I would like a query that removes the following in bold if that is possible..

http://google.com//<--- remove the extra forward slash

http:// <--- Not to be touched

If anyone knows a MySQL query for this that would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `REPLACE` function. It requires three parameters

- first is the source string,
- second is the string to be searched for
- and third is the string to replace

  UPDATE pages SET url=REPLACE(url, '.com//', '.com/') WHERE url LIKE '%.com//%'